# how to iterate over 2 array list

Tags: java, list

I have java object containing one more object .

```
public class ParameterValue {            
        private Property property;            
        private String PropertyValue;            
        public static class Property {               
               private String paramName;        
        }
}
```

In  my util method i get all the property names in a list

```
 List<ParameterValue.Property> properties=   getAllParameter();    
 List<ParameterValue> paramValues= getAllParameterValues();
```

which returns me only `ParameterValue` objets only values are set.

Now i want to get Property object from properties list and set in paramvalues list creating a full object. How can i do it. Is it possible to iterate over 2 lists

Comment: Context is a little unclear, but you might be better off using a `java.util.Map`, mapping `ParameterValue.Property` to `ParamaterValue`s.

Comment: You are actually not very clear with your question.. Can you elaborate a little more what you want to achieve??

Comment: I am getting inner object1 from one method as a list and outer object2 fr m other method where only string value is set.I want to inject object 1 to object 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the standard forloop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < properties.size(); i++) {
  properties.get(i); //get the ParameterValue.Property
  paramValues.get(i); //get the ParmeterValue
}
```

Comment: I have logic to get the objects but i want to inject property into param value object

Answer (score 2):

If the corresponding entry at index `N` in `properties` list corresponds to the same index `N` in `paramValues` list you can iterate using an `int` counter and use [`List.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29):

```
// assert properties.size() == paramValues.size();
for (int idx = 0, size = properties.size(); idx < size; idx++)
{
    ParameterValue.Property prop = properties.get(idx);
    ParameterValue value = paramValues.get(idx);
}
```

Comment: How can i set it i can get an object from counter inside for loop for setting how to go about it?

Comment: I can get the object but i want to construct outer object using inner object and value which i have got from 2 separate methods

Comment: @constantlearner, the answer illustrates how get access to the elements. If you need to update the `ParameterValue` instance you some `public` method(s) to permit this (the posted code in the question does not show any).

Comment: thanks for your inputs i have logic to fetch the objects but how to set it  while(){ and again for loop inside}